# How do "automatic updates" in Next.js work?

Tags: next.js

In the Next.js docs, there is a mention of [automatic updates](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment#automatic-updates):

> When you deploy your Next.js application, you want to see the latest version without needing to reload.
>
> Next.js will automatically load the latest version of your application in the background when routing. For client-side navigations, next/link will temporarily function as a normal  tag.

I am interested in how this works, but can't figure it out by looking at the Next.js source code. I understand that once an updated version on the server is detected, the client side links become normal `<a>` tags and so a full page load will occur, allowing the new HTML and new JS/CSS assets to load.

The bit I'm not sure about is *how* Next.js detects that a newly deployed version is available on the server. What am I missing?